# How to render images in React when the image names contain white spaces?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, image

I'm using React to reference a number of (local) images that have white space in their names. E.g.

```
<img src={`/images/${user.name}.jpg`} />
```

However, React is unable to load/render the image. The image are in the `/public` folder and I double checked the file names/paths. I also tried using `encodeURIComponent()` for the path, but that didn't work either. However, when I removed the white space from the image name, React was able to render the image properly.

Answer (score 0):

please encode file name using `encodeURIComponent`

```
<img src={`/images/${encodeURIComponent(user.name)}.jpg`} />
```

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I had already tried `encodeURIComponent` -- this didn't work.

Comment: oh, sorry. so image with non-space filename works properly?